# Nginx reverse proxy using try_files is serving php files unparsed

Tags: php, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy to Apache which is handling PHP, here's my nginx site config:

```
server {
        listen   80 default;
        server_name  localhost;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

        root /var/www/www.example.com/httpdocs;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                proxy_pass              http://www.example.com:80;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny  all;
        }

        #location / {
                try_files $uri @proxy;
        #}

        location @proxy {
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                client_max_body_size    10m;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;
                proxy_connect_timeout   90;
                proxy_send_timeout      90;
                proxy_read_timeout      90;
                proxy_buffers           32 4k;
                proxy_pass              http://www.example.com:81;
        }
}
```

My issue is that requests for `index.php` are being returned by nginx unparsed, so my location specifically for handling php files is not doing what it should.

If I request `index.php?q=whatever`, which is a valid request for apache, then the site returns a 500 with the error:

```
2012/07/13 11:22:27 [alert] 8490#0: *17994 4096 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php?q=whatever HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/index.php?q=whatever", host: "www.example.com"
```

Comment: nginx is just proxying, and shouldn't be doing anything with the PHP files.  What's Apache's config look like for executing the PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_pass              http://www.example.com:80;
    }
```

In your configuration, Nginx is listening in port 80. So passing index.php file to Nginx (port 80) will leave it unparsed. So, assuming that Apache listens on port 81, the correct `proxy_pass` directive would be...

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_pass              http://www.example.com:81;
    }
```

To know more about how Nginx handles proxy requests, please check out the official wiki on [HttpProxyModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule).

Comment: Haha, oops, I'll fix that ASAP and see how it goes! I had originally ran nginx on 81 to leave apache on 80 as it was originally. That'll teach me to DRY.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, @DanH!